# Multiple entry points in flutter(flavors for android & iOS)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I have created new flavors (schemes) prod and dev. I have 2 main entry points in my flutter app.

I want to change the entry point according to the selected scheme/flavor i.e. in the prod scheme main file would be main_prod.dart and for dev, it would be main_dev.dart.

flutter run -t lib/main_prod.dart --flavor prod
flutter run -t lib/main_dev.dart --flavor dev

With the above commands, two new app were installed on my device but both have the same entry point in iOS. i.e. main_dev.dart

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.